# Opera always re-requests proxy authentication after restart

Tags: proxy, opera, ntlm

Both 9.xx and 10.xx versions of Opera are re-requesting proxy auth after the browser restarts. The login and password inputs are already filled in so I need just click OK button but I need to do this for every tab a few times.

How can I stop it? In internet Explorer and Firefox everything is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opera seems to have a problem with NTLM (Windows authentication) proxy servers.

This seems to be a common workaround: [NTLMAPS](http://ntlmaps.sourceforge.net/)
And it's described [here](http://my.opera.com/Tamil/blog/index.dml/tag/NTLM).

NTLMAPS is a little proxy server which you run on your PC; it sits between Opera (once you configure Opera to use it) and your Windows auth proxy server, and handles the NTLM authentication which Opera cannot yet do.

Comment: Lol. Python + nanoproxy to solve tiny bug ) But it works. Thanks.